# How do I send a POST request as a JSON?

Tags: python, json, http, url, post

```
data = {
        'ids': [12, 3, 4, 5, 6 , ...]
    }
    urllib2.urlopen("http://abc.example/api/posts/create",urllib.urlencode(data))
```

I want to send a POST request, but one of the fields should be a list of numbers. How can I do that? (JSON?)

Comment: Isn't that already a list of numbers, though?

Comment: This can't be answered without knowing what kind of input the API expects.

Comment: @WaynnLue the API server is getting that as a string, not a list.

Comment: Do I have to set headers as "application/json" or something?

Comment: Related: [Python 3 urlopen context manager mocking](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32043035/1015595)

Answer (score 160, accepted):

If your server is expecting the POST request to be json, then you would need to add a header, and also serialize the data for your request...

*Python 2.x*

```
import json
import urllib2

data = {
        'ids': [12, 3, 4, 5, 6]
}

req = urllib2.Request('http://example.com/api/posts/create')
req.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')

response = urllib2.urlopen(req, json.dumps(data))
```

*Python 3.x*

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26876308/496445

---

If you don't specify the header, it will be the default `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` type.

Comment: I have a question. is it possible to add multiple items in the header... like content type & client-id... @jdi

Comment: @OmarJandali, just call `add_header()` again, for each header you want to add.

Comment: i have the following coded but it is not printing anything. it was supposed to print the url and headers but nothing was printed... `req = urllib.Request('http://uat-api.synapsefi.com')
    req.add_header('X-SP-GATEWAY', 'client_id_asdfeavea561va9685e1gre5ara|client_secret_4651av5sa1edgvawegv1a6we1v5a6s51gv')
    req.add_header('X-SP-USER-IP', '127.0.0.1')
    req.add_header('X-SP-USER', '| ge85a41v8e16v1a618gea164g65')
    req.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')

    print(req)`...

Comment: urllib2 was not recognized so i just used urllib. i am also getting an error with the request. `The view tab.views.profileSetup didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.`  @jdi

Comment: @OmarJandali, please keep in mind that this answer was originally given in 2012, under python 2.x. You are using Python3 so the imports will be different. It would now be `import urllib.request` and `urllib.request.Request()`. Furthermore, printing the req object does nothing interesting. You can clearly see the headers have been added by printing `req.headers`. Beyond that, I am not sur why it isn't working in your application.

Comment: So i have two lines that i made changes to `response = urllib.request.Request(req, json.dumps(data))` and `req = urllib.request.Request('http://uat-api.synapsefi.com')`. i am getting a message saying `unknown url type: 'urllib.request.Request object at 0x00000250B05474A8'` from the second line that i made changes to... what is the way fro me to change the url type @jdi

Comment: @OmarJandali, you aren't calling `urlopen()` like the original example. That is why you are getting an error. See: https://pastebin.com/1gUdGYcP

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153654/discussion-between-omar-jandali-and-jdi).

Comment: Than you so much, it is working and sending a response. it is sending a response in the wrong format `POST data should be bytes, an iterable of bytes, or a file object. It cannot be of type str.`

Comment: The python3 version is the one here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26876308/5973334  – better merge it with the accepted answer

Comment: @Kuzeko, thanks. I have added that reference to my answer

Answer (score 121):

I recommend using the incredible `requests` module.

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/v0.10.7/user/quickstart/#custom-headers

```
url = 'https://api.github.com/some/endpoint'
payload = {'some': 'data'}
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}

response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
```

Comment: This gives me `TypeError: post() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`

Comment: It is much more succinct to just use `json=payload` (which may have been introduced since this answer was written long ago) without specifying the header or calling `json.dumps()`. See other answers on this page.

Answer (score 92):

For python 3.4.2, I found the following will work:

```
import urllib.request
import json

body = {'ids': [12, 14, 50]}
myurl = "http://www.testmycode.example"

req = urllib.request.Request(myurl)
req.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8')
jsondata = json.dumps(body)
jsondataasbytes = jsondata.encode('utf-8')   # needs to be bytes
req.add_header('Content-Length', len(jsondataasbytes))
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req, jsondataasbytes)
```

Comment: Python3.6.2 this worked. Only adding header with req.add_header(...) worked for me.

Comment: You do not need to specify the `Content-Length` header, it will be calculated by `urllib` automatically.

Answer (score 20):

This works perfect for `Python 3.5`, if the URL contains Query String / Parameter value,

Request URL = `https://bah2.example/ws/rest/v1/concept/`
Parameter value = 21f6bb43-98a1-419d-8f0c-8133669e40ca

```
import requests

url = 'https://bahbah2.example/ws/rest/v1/concept/21f6bb43-98a1-419d-8f0c-8133669e40ca'
data = {"name": "Value"}
r = requests.post(url, auth=('username', 'password'), json=data)
print(r.status_code)
```

Comment: in your code snipper, headers variable stays unused

Comment: **This answer is insecure.** Do not pass `verify=False`, which disables certificate validation and opens your code up to man-the-middle attacks.

Comment: I removed `verify=False` from the code sample to resolve the above comment.

Answer (score 13):

Here is an example of how to use urllib.request object from Python standard library.

```
import urllib.request
import json
from pprint import pprint

url = "https://app.close.com/hackwithus/3d63efa04a08a9e0/"

values = {
    "first_name": "Vlad",
    "last_name": "Bezden",
    "urls": [
        "https://twitter.com/VladBezden",
        "https://github.com/vlad-bezden",
    ],
}


headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Accept": "application/json",
}

data = json.dumps(values).encode("utf-8")
pprint(data)

try:
    req = urllib.request.Request(url, data, headers)
    with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as f:
        res = f.read()
    pprint(res.decode())
except Exception as e:
    pprint(e)
```

Comment: works great using standard library urllib. Don't forget the data in Request(url, data, headers), otherwise it would look like a GET to the server.

Comment: @ApurvaSingh Putting the `data` automatically creates a 'Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8' header, like in the other answer?

Comment: @Jay turn on http connection debugging in Python code and check request headers in the output log

Answer (score 4):

You have to add header,or you will get http 400 error.
The code works well on python2.6,centos5.4

code:

```
    import urllib2,json

    url = 'http://www.google.com/someservice'
    postdata = {'key':'value'}

    req = urllib2.Request(url)
    req.add_header('Content-Type','application/json')
    data = json.dumps(postdata)

    response = urllib2.urlopen(req,data)
```

Comment: Note: This answer is very old and `urllib2` has been removed in Python 3. Look for other examples using `urllib` or `requests`.

Answer (score 4):

In the lastest requests package, you can use `json` parameter in [`requests.post()`](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.post) method to send a json dict, and the `Content-Type` in header will be set to `application/json`. There is no need to specify header explicitly.

```py
import requests

payload = {'key': 'value'}
requests.post(url, json=payload)
```

Comment: Note that this will result in POSTed json with single quotes, which is technically invalid.

Comment: @Jethro Have you observed errors when using single quotes? It is valid to use single quotes in Python. Personally, I haven't met any issues regarding this.

Comment: Aah apologies I was mistaken, I thought my server was receiving single-quoted JSON but It turned out to be a separate issue and some misleading debugging. Cheers, this is much tidier than having to specify the header manually!

Answer (score 3):

The [Requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io) package used in many answers here is great but not necessary. You can perform a POST of JSON data succinctly with the Python 3 standard library in one step:

```py
import json
from urllib import request

request.urlopen(request.Request(
    'https://example.com/url',
    headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    data=json.dumps({
        'pi': 3.14159
    }).encode()
))
```

If you need to read the result, you can `.read()` from the returned file-like object and use `json.loads()` to decode a JSON response.

Answer (score 1):

This one works fine for me with apis

```
import requests

data={'Id':id ,'name': name}
r = requests.post( url = 'https://apiurllink', data = data)
```

Comment: This is an incorrect answer. The `data=data` parameter sends a **form-encoded** request, which is not JSON. Use `json=data` instead.