# Regex search with variable in Python 2.7 returns bytes instead of decoded text

Tags: regex, python-2.7, encoding, utf-8

The words of the "wordslist" and the text I'm searching are in Cyrillic. The text is coded in UTF-8 (as set in Notepad++). I need Python to match a word in the text and get everything after the word until a full-stop followed by new line.

EDIT

```
with open('C:\....txt', 'rb') as f:
    wordslist = []
    for line in f:
        wordslist.append(line) 

wordslist = map(str.strip, wordslist)
```

/EDIT

```
for i in wordslist:
    print i #so far, so good, I get Cyrillic
    wantedtext = re.findall(i+".*\.\r\n", open('C:\....txt', 'rb').read())
    wantedtext = str(wantedtext)
    print wantedtext
```

"Wantedtext" shows and saves as "\xd0\xb2" (etc.).

**What I tried:**

This question is different, because there is no variable involved:
[Convert bytes to a python string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-bytes-to-a-python-string?rq=1). Also, the solution from the chosen answer

```
wantedtext.decode('utf-8')
```

didn't work, the result was the same. The solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13837848/converting-byte-string-in-unicode-string) didn't help either.

EDIT: Revised code, returning "[]".

```
with io.open('C:....txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    wordslist = f.read().splitlines() 

for i in wordslist:
    print i
    with io.open('C:....txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as my_file:
        my_file_test = my_file.read()
        print my_file_test #works, prints cyrillic characters, but...


        wantedtext = re.findall(i+".*\.\r\n", my_file_test)
        wantedtext = str(wantedtext)

        print wantedtext #returns []
```

(Added after a comment below: This code works if you erase \r from the regular expression.)

Comment: Where's the bit of code where you load the wordlist and save it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Python 2.x only

Your `find` is probably not working because you're mixing strs and Unicodes strs, or strs containing different encodings. If you don't know what the difference between Unicode str and str, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35444608/1554386

Don't start `decoding` stuff unless you know what you're doing. It's not voodoo :)

You need to get all your text into Unicode objects first.

1. Split your read into a separate line - it's easier to read
2. Decode your text file. Use `io.open()` which support Python 3 decoding. I'm going assume your text file is UTF-8 (We'll soon find out if it's not):

   ```
   with io.open('C:\....txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as my_file:
       my_file_test = my_file.read()
   ```

   `my_file_test` is now a Unicode str
3. Now you can do:

   ```
   # finds lines beginning with i, ending in .
   regex = u'^{i}*?\.$'.format(i=i)
   wantedtext = re.findall(regex, my_file_test, re.M)
   ```
4. Look at `wordslist`. You don't say what you do with it but you need to make sure it's a Unicode str too. If you read from a file, use the same `io.open` from above.

Edit:

For `wordslist`, you can decode and read the file into a list while removing line feeds in one go:

```
with io.open('C:\....txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    wordslist = f.read().splitlines()
```

Comment: I get NameError: name 'io' is not defined. Do I need a package to use io.open?

Comment: yes, it's often implied on Stack Overflow when you see an unqualified package. `import io`

Comment: The program is running, it prints a word from a list, and then no result - [].

Comment: sorry, I screwed the `wordlist` logic during my edit. Please see update with `io.open()`. If it still doesn't work, then you'll have to provide more information

Comment: It looks like you're trying find all lines which start with a word and ends with `.`. Right? Because you're now using a file reader that supports Universal new line, you need to use proper regex line markers

Comment: Good stuff. Check out my latest changes though - It uses the `re.M` flag for multiline and a non-greedy search