# How to convert bytes data to string without changing data using python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I convert bytes to string without changing data ?
E.g
**Input:**
`file_data = b'\xb4\xeb7s\x14q[\xc4\xbb\x8e\xd4\xe0\x01\xec+\x8f\xf8c\xff\x00 \xeb\xff'`

**Output:**
`'\xb4\xeb7s\x14q[\xc4\xbb\x8e\xd4\xe0\x01\xec+\x8f\xf8c\xff\x00 \xeb\xff'`

I want to write an image data using StringIO with some additional data, Below is my code snippet,

```
img_buf = StringIO()
f = open("Sample_image.jpg", "rb")
file_data = f.read()
img_buf.write('\r\n' + file_data + '\r\n')
```

This works fine with python 2.7 but I want it to be working with python 3.4.
on read operation `file_data = f.read()` returns bytes object data something like this

```
b'\xb4\xeb7s\x14q[\xc4\xbb\x8e\xd4\xe0\x01\xec+\x8f\xf8c\xff\x00 \xeb\xff'
```

While writting data using `img_buf` it accepts only String data, so unable to write `file_data` with some additional characters.
So I want to convert `file_data` as it is in String object without changing its data. Something like this

```
'\xb4\xeb7s\x14q[\xc4\xbb\x8e\xd4\xe0\x01\xec+\x8f\xf8c\xff\x00 \xeb\xff'
```

so that I can concat and write the image data.

I don't want to decode or encode data. Any suggestions would be helpful for me. thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you asking how to convert the bytes data to a string?  Just `my_string = file_data.decode('utf-8')`?  (Realize that decoding is literally converting bytes to a string... are you **sure** you don't want to decode it?)

Comment: `my_string = file_data.decode('utf-8')`  Gives error as `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb4 in position 0: invalid start byte`

Comment: I won't try to close this as a duplicate, because I don't yet understand what you want, but does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13837848/converting-byte-string-in-unicode-string?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa solve your problem?

Comment: No it doesn't solve my problem. I just want bytes data to string as it is without changing bytes data.

Comment: Actually, I'll step it back a bit.  Please read [ask].  Your title mentions "bytes data of an image".  This is presumably 64-bit encoded image data that you're loading.  With the appropriate functions, you can convert this data to an image.  Why do you want it to be a string?  Can you please [edit] your question to tell us what exactly you're trying to do with it?

Comment: Yes sure @ScottMermelstein

Comment: You'll need to explain better what you mean by "without changing data".  The data doesn't change; simply the way it is interpretted does when you use decode.  I'll just leave this here as recommended reading, and wish you good luck.  https://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/unicode.html

Comment: Thanks @ScottMermelstein

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear what kind of output you desire.  If you are interested in *aesthetically* translating bytes to a string representation without encoding:

```
s = str(file_data)[1:]
print(s)
# '\xb4\xeb7s\x14q[\xc4\xbb\x8e\xd4\xe0\x01\xec+\x8f\xf8c\xff\x00 \xeb\xff'
```

This is the [informal string representation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) of the original byte string (no conversion).

---

**Details**

The [official string representation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) looks like this:

```
s
# "'\\xb4\\xeb7s\\x14q[\\xc4\\xbb\\x8e\\xd4\\xe0\\x01\\xec+\\x8f\\xf8c\\xff\\x00 \\xeb\\xff'"
```

*String representation handles how a string looks.*  Double escape characters and double quotes are implicitly interpreted in Python to do the right thing so that the `print` function outputs a formatted string.

*String intrepretation handles what a string means.*  Each block of characters means something different depending on the applied encoding.  Here we interpret these blocks of characters (e.g. `\\xb4`, `\\xeb`, `7`, `s`) with the `UTF-8` encoding.  Blocks unrecognized by this encoding are replaced with a default character, �:

```
file_data.decode("utf-8", "replace")
# '��7s\x14q[Ļ���\x01�+��c�\x00 ��'
```

Converting from bytes to strings is required for reliably working with strings.

In short, there is a difference in string output between how it looks (representation) and what it means (interpretation).  Clarify which you prefer and proceed accordingly.

**Addendum**

If your question is "how do I concatenate a byte string?", here is one approach:

```
buffer = io.BytesIO()
with buffer as f:
    f.write(b"\r\n")
    f.write(file_data)
    f.write(b"\r\n")
    print(buffer.getvalue())
# b'\r\n\xb4\xeb7s\x14q[\xc4\xbb\x8e\xd4\xe0\x01\xec+\x8f\xf8c\xff\x00 \xeb\xff\r\n'
```

Equivalently:

```
buffer = b""
buffer += b"\r\n"
buffer += file_data
buffer += b"\r\n"
buffer
# b'\r\n\xb4\xeb7s\x14q[\xc4\xbb\x8e\xd4\xe0\x01\xec+\x8f\xf8c\xff\x00 \xeb\xff\r\n'
```

Comment: I tried both of ways you mentioned in answer. `file_data = str(file_data)[2:-1]` returns String like  `'\\xb4\\xeb7s\\x14q[\\xc4\\xbb\\x8e\\xd4\\xe0\\x01\\xec+\\x8f\\xf8c\\xff\\x00 \\xeb\\xff'` which contains escaped backslashes and I dont want escaped backslashes. I have added brief explanation in question for more information. Thanks @pylang

Comment: `s` has escaped characters because it is a string.   To my knowledge, you cannot change that (and probably should not try).  It seems like you just want to append data to a byte string, correct?  If so, is it necessary to have a string result?  How about modifying a byte string instead?