# Send json data to php api through python

Tags: php, python, json

I am new to python. I have created a gui based app to insert values into database.
I have created a Rest api to handle db operations. How can i append the api URL with json created in python.

app.py

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
import json
import requests
from urllib import urlopen


top = Tk()
L1 = Label(top, text="Title")
L1.pack( side = TOP)
E1 = Entry(top, bd =5)
E1.pack(side = TOP)


L2 = Label(top, text="Author")
L2.pack( side = TOP)
E2 = Entry(top, bd =5)
E2.pack(side = TOP)

L3 = Label(top, text="Body")
L3.pack( side = TOP)
E3 = Entry(top, bd =5)
E3.pack(side = TOP)
input = E2.get();

def callfunc():
data = {"author": E2.get(),
    "body" : E3.get(),
    "title" : E1.get()}
data_json = json.dumps(data)

# r = requests.get('http://localhost/spritle/api.php?action=get_uses')
#url = "http://localhost/spritle/api.php?action=insert_list&data_json="
#
url = urlopen("http://localhost/spritle/api.php?action=insert_list&data_json="%data_json).read()

tkMessageBox.showinfo("Result",data_json)
 SubmitButton = Button(text="Submit", fg="White", bg="#0094FF", 
                  font=("Grobold", 10), command = callfunc)
 SubmitButton.pack()


 top.mainloop()
```

Error:

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

i AM GETTING error while appending url with data_json ?

Answer (score 0):

There is an error on string formating:

Swap this:

```
"http://localhost/spritle/api.php?action=insert_list&data_json="%data_json
```

by this:

```
"http://localhost/spritle/api.php?action=insert_list&data_json=" + data_json
```

or:

```
"http://localhost/spritle/api.php?action=insert_list&data_json={}".format(data_json)
```

The following statements are equivalents:

```
"Python with " + "PHP"
"Python with %s" % "PHP"
"Python with {}".format("PHP")
"Python with {lang}".format(lang="PHP")
```

Also, I don't think sending JSON data like this via URL is a good idea. You should encode the data at least.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use `%` operator to format the string, and you need to put the `%s` placeholder into the string:

```
"http://localhost/spritle/api.php?action=insert_list&data_json=%s" % data_json
```

Or use other methods suggested in another answer.

Regarding the data transfer - you definitely need to use POST request and not GET.
Check [this, using urllib2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9746303/how-do-i-send-a-post-request-as-a-json) and [this, using requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733638/post-json-using-python-requests).