# python - POST request doesn't work

Tags: python, http, web-scraping, python-requests

I copied the POST data using chrome developer tools, and put them into a text file.

```
from pprint import pprint
import requests

d= {}    
with open('form1.txt') as g:
    stuff = g.readlines()

for sindex, s in enumerate(stuff):
    line = s.replace('http://', 'REPLACETHISREPLACETHIS').replace('\n', '').split(':')

    for index, l in enumerate(line):    
        if (index > 1):
            print('index too big')
            print(index)
            print(line)
            while True:
                pass

        line[index] = l.replace('REPLACETHISREPLACETHIS', 'http://').encode('utf-8')
    d[line[0]] = line[1]

r = requests.post('http://search.cpsa.ca/PhysicianSearch', data = d)

print(r.text)
print(r.status_code)
print('done!')
```

console:

```
1|#||4|50|pageRedirect||%2fError.aspx%3faspxerrorpath%3d%2fPhysicianSearch|
200
done!
```

Why might this be occurring? I copied the form data directly from chrome so I don't believe there could be any errors.

Comment: what do you mean you _copied the form data directly from chrome_? what does the file actually contain?

Comment: Can you show what your `d` variable is before you post it?

Comment: You need to add more information to this. What data???

Comment: The file is too large to post here. http://imgur.com/GJX2T3P is a screenshot. It's the form data which I got from pressing a certain button on the site.

Comment: Try going to the target page in your browser, what do you see? Open your network tab while you do that. See if the error code is 302 or 200 or anything else. I don't know what you meant by 'copied from chrome'. There was an exact code some where?

Comment: OP is following on from this q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36484184/python-make-a-post-request-using-python-3-urllib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok it is actually a lot more involved, we need to parse the values from the page to pass i.e `__EVENTVALIDATION`, `__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR` etc..m I used [bs4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to parse the required values after doing an initial get:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

d = {"ctl00$ctl13": "ctl00$ctl13|ctl00$MainContent$physicianSearchView$btnSearch",
     "ctl00$MainContent$physicianSearchView$txtLastName": "Train",
     'ctl00$MainContent$physicianSearchView$txtFirstName': "Anthony",
     'ctl00$MainContent$physicianSearchView$txtCity': "Calgary",
     "__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED":"",
     'ctl00$MainContent$physicianSearchView$txtPostalCode': "",
     'ctl00$MainContent$physicianSearchView$rblPractice': "",
     'ctl00$MainContent$physicianSearchView$ddDiscipline': "",
     'ctl00$MainContent$physicianSearchView$rblGender': "Male",
     'ctl00$MainContent$physicianSearchView$txtPracticeInterests': "",
     'ctl00$MainContent$physicianSearchView$ddApprovals': "",
     'ctl00$MainContent$physicianSearchView$ddLanguage': "",
     "__EVENTTARGET": "ctl00$MainContent$physicianSearchView$btnSearch",
     "__EVENTARGUMENT": "",
     'ctl00$MainContent$physicianSearchView$hfPrefetchUrl': "http://service.cpsa.ca/OnlineService/OnlineService.svc/Services/GetAlbertaCities?name=",
     'ctl00$MainContent$physicianSearchView$hfRemoveUrl': "http://service.cpsa.ca/OnlineService/OnlineService.svc/Services/GetAlbertaCities?name=%QUERY",
     '__ASYNCPOST': 'true'}

h ={ "X-MicrosoftAjax":"Delta = true",
"X-Requested-With":"XMLHttpRequest",
     "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36"
}

with requests.session() as s:
    r = s.get("http://search.cpsa.ca/PhysicianSearch",headers=h)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
    ev = soup.select("#__EVENTVALIDATION" )[0]["value"]
    vs = soup.select("#__VIEWSTATE")[0]["value"]
    vsg = soup.select("#__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR")[0]["value"]
    d["__EVENTVALIDATION"] = ev
    d["__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR"] = vsg
    d["__VIEWSTATE"] = vs
    r = requests.post('http://search.cpsa.ca/PhysicianSearch', data=d,headers=h)
    print(r.content)
```

Now we get data back at the end of the content:

```
<div>
    <table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="MainContent_physicianSearchView_gvResults" style="border-style:None;border-collapse:collapse;">
        <tr class="tHeader">
            <th class="rhStatus" scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$physicianSearchView$gvResults&#39;,&#39;Sort$AcceptingNewPatients&#39;)"></a></th><th class="rhName" scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$physicianSearchView$gvResults&#39;,&#39;Sort$FormattedName&#39;)">Name</a></th><th class="rhLocation" scope="col"><span>Location</span></th><th class="rhType" scope="col"><span>Practice Discipline</span></th><th class="rhGender" scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$physicianSearchView$gvResults&#39;,&#39;Sort$Gender&#39;)">Gender</a></th><th class="rhLang" scope="col"><span>Languages</span></th>
        </tr><tr>
            <td class="status1">
                                    1
                                </td><td>
                                    <a href="http://search.cpsa.ca/PhysicianProfile?e=maso3IsrrLGqxtPPO2xIAA%3d%3d">Train, Dr. Anthony</a>
                                </td><td>

                                    <div>

                                        <p>100-300 6 AVE SE</p>
                                        <p></p>
                                        <p></p>
                                        <p>Calgary, Alberta, Canada</p>
                                        <p>T2G 0G5</p>
                                        <p><a class="phInfo" href="tel:403-775-9669">403-775-9669</a></p>
                                        <p class="faxInfo">403-775-9812</span></p>

            </div>
                                </td><td>

                                    <div>

                                        Family Medicine

            </div>
                                </td><td>
                                    Male
                                </td><td>
                                    English
                                </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        |0|hiddenField|__EVENTTARGET||0|hiddenField|__EVENTARGUMENT||15104|hiddenField|__VIEWSTATE|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|8|hiddenField|__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR|4424DBE6|0|hiddenField|__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED||7000|hiddenField|__EVENTVALIDATION|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|177|asyncPostBackControlIDs||ctl00$MainContent$physicianSearchView$btnClear,MainContent_physicianSearchView_btnClear,ctl00$MainContent$physicianSearchView$btnSearch,MainContent_physicianSearchView_btnSearch|0|postBackControlIDs|||193|updatePanelIDs||fctl00$MainContent$physicianSearchView$UpdatePanel1,MainContent_physicianSearchView_UpdatePanel1,tctl00$MainContent$physicianSearchView$ResultsPanel,MainContent_physicianSearchView_ResultsPanel|0|childUpdatePanelIDs|||95|panelsToRefreshIDs||ctl00$MainContent$physicianSearchView$ResultsPanel,MainContent_physicianSearchView_ResultsPanel|2|asyncPostBackTimeout||90|17|formAction||./PhysicianSearch|
```

To minimum needed to get the result above is:

```
h ={ "X-MicrosoftAjax":"Delta = true",
"X-Requested-With":"XMLHttpRequest",
     "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36"
}

d = {"ctl00$ctl13": "ctl00$ctl13|ctl00$MainContent$physicianSearchView$btnSearch",
     "ctl00$MainContent$physicianSearchView$txtLastName": "Train",
     'ctl00$MainContent$physicianSearchView$txtFirstName': "Anthony",
     'ctl00$MainContent$physicianSearchView$txtCity': "Calgary",
     'ctl00$MainContent$physicianSearchView$rblGender': "Male",
     "__EVENTTARGET": "ctl00$MainContent$physicianSearchView$btnSearch",
     'ctl00$MainContent$physicianSearchView$hfPrefetchUrl': "http://service.cpsa.ca/OnlineService/OnlineService.svc/Services/GetAlbertaCities?name=",
     'ctl00$MainContent$physicianSearchView$hfRemoveUrl': "http://service.cpsa.ca/OnlineService/OnlineService.svc/Services/GetAlbertaCities?name=%QUERY",
     '__ASYNCPOST': 'true'}


with requests.session() as s:
    r = s.get("http://search.cpsa.ca/PhysicianSearch",headers=h)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"lxml")
    ev = soup.select("#__EVENTVALIDATION" )[0]["value"]
    vs = soup.select("#__VIEWSTATE")[0]["value"]
    d["__EVENTVALIDATION"] = ev
    d["__VIEWSTATE"] = vs
    r = requests.post('http://search.cpsa.ca/PhysicianSearch', data=d,headers=h)
    print(r.content)
```

Your post was missing those values, if you remove the any of the values I add in the with you will see the same output as your own code:

```
   1|#||4|50|pageRedirect||%2fError.aspx%3faspxerrorpath%3d%2fPhysicianSearch|
```

Comment: How did you figure this out?

Comment: @DanielPaczuskiBak, you need to crack open the chrome developer tools, firebug etc. and have a look at the network tab when you make a requests, you have to see what was posted and try to mimic

Comment: How would you navigate to the next page? I still don't really understand how you knew to just copy data that was just on the DOM, but that strategy doesn't seem to be working again.

Comment: the code is still working for me, are you saying it does not work for you?

Comment: It works for me - I just wonder how you would modify it such that for multi-page searches, you move to the next page. (Try searching with nothing in the form).