# How do we use POST method in Python using urllib.request?

Tags: python-3.x, urllib

I have to make use of POST method using urllib.request in Python and have written the following code for POST method.

```
values = {"abcd":"efgh"}
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json", "Authorization": "Basic"+str(authKey)}
req = urllib.request.Request(url,values,headers=headers,method='POST')
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
print(response.read())
```

I am able to make use of **'GET'** and **'DELETE'** but not **'POST'**.Could anyone help me out in solving this?
Thanks

Comment: add `url` in the question, what is it?

Answer (score 3):

If you really have to use `urllib.request` in POST, you have to:

1. Encode your data using `urllib.parse.urlencode()`(if sending a form)
2. Convert encoded data to `bytes`
3. Specify `Content-Type` header (`application/octet-stream` for raw binary data, `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` for forms , `multipart/form-data` for forms containing files and `application/json` for JSON)

If you do all of this, your code should be like:

```py
req=urllib.request.Request(url,
     urllib.parse.urlencode(data).encode(),
     headers={"Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
)
urlopen=urllib.request.urlopen(req)
response=urlopen.read()
```

(for forms)
or

```py
req=urllib.request.Request(url,
     json.dumps(data).encode(),
     headers={"Content-Type":"application/json"}
)
urlopen=urllib.request.urlopen(req)
response=urlopen.read()
```

(for JSON).
[Sending files](https://gist.github.com/jenca-adam/20f29f6180506fceb0b9f7dbbb4a0855) is a bit more complicated.

From `urllib.request`'s [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#:%7E:text=For%20an%20HTTP%20POST%20request%20method):

> For an HTTP POST request method, data should be a buffer in the
> standard application/x-www-form-urlencoded format. The
> urllib.parse.urlencode() function takes a mapping or sequence of
> 2-tuples and returns an ASCII string in this format. It should be
> encoded to bytes before being used as the data parameter.

Read more:

- [Python - make a POST request using Python 3 urllib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36484184/python-make-a-post-request-using-python-3-urllib)
- [RFC 7578 - Returning Values from Forms: multipart/form-data](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7578)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the requests module for this.

```
import requests
...
url="https://example.com/"
print url
data = {'id':"1", 'value': 1}
r = requests.post(url, data=data)
print(r.text)
print(r.status_code, r.reason)
```

Comment: WIthout requests and with urllib.request , is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

You can send calls without installing any additional packages.

Call this function with your input data and url. function will return the response.

```
from urllib import request
import json

def make_request(input_data, url):
    # dict to Json, then convert to string and then to bytes
    input_data = str(json.dumps(input_data)).encode('utf-8')

    # Post Method is invoked if data != None
    req =  request.Request(url, data=input_data)
    return request.urlopen(req).read().decode('utf-8')
```