# Replicating wget command with Python's urllib?

Tags: python, http

I am trying to use a web API in my Python program, but I can't figure out how.

Here is an example call using the command line in Bash/Unix:

`wget --post-file="example.txt" "http://example.com/api" -O output_filename`

How would I replicate this functionality with Python's `urllib` module? I'm reading through the documentation for the module, but I'm not quite sure how to send a POST request to the website with a file attached. Any help or advice would be appreciated.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36484184/python-make-a-post-request-using-python-3-urllib) answer to a question a few years ago that seems to be doing something along the lines of what I am trying to do, but I don't seems to be getting the desired result when I try to replicate it:

```py
from urllib import request, parse
data = parse.urlencode('example.txt').encode()
req =  request.Request('http://example.com/api', data=data) 
resp = request.urlopen(req)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd highly recommend using the [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/) package over `urllib`.

Making a `POST` request is as easy as:

```py
import requests

payload = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
r = requests.post("https://httpbin.org/post", data=payload)
print(r.text)
```

Output:

```
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {
    "key1": "value1", 
    "key2": "value2"
  },
```

Comment: What would the payload dictionary be in my case? I know that wget's --post-file takes things as key-value pairs, but I just tried experimenting with the code you provided and I couldn't get it to work.