# Can a json file be posted as is to the http server?

Tags: python, json, http, httprequest, httpresponse

I have a file as follows:

```
{
    "http-request": {
        "header": {
            "method": "POST",
            "action": "register",
            "httpversion": "1.1",
            "host": "customerrequest.com",
            "Connection": "keepalive",
            "Content-Length": "254",
            "Origin": "https://clipboard.customerrequest.com",
            "User-Agent": "Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36"
        },
        "body": {
            "email": "jen@gmail.com",
            "password": "XXXXXXXX",
            "confirm_password": "XXXXXXXX",
            "invite_code": "",
            "csrf_token": "gshdgagTTDBsbasxgvdfjdkf-TI1kV42pAYhkFXQrKfvJjLYhpR-fJ2WjirVXaQ==",
        }
    }
}
```

I need to post this info to the server `https://clipboard.customerrequest.com` for server action register. I am a total noob with the whole http request response etc. I just need a little help here understanding

1. Should I post the whole json as is to the server? If not, what is the best way to post this information to the server?
2. When I get a response, I want to automatically parse the response and store the information.How can I convert the response body (http I think) to json format?
3. I want to do this in python. Any resources/libraries I can look at?

Comment: first of all is your server accepting header content type "Application/json". if yes you can post your data as it is to it

Comment: @AlokVishwakarma I think they accept content type `text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8`

Comment: Ooh there is no application/json tag, i think it  should also accpet application/json other wise you can not post you data in json format.
is that server belongs to you then you can change the accepted header.
for now you you can only post your data as Parameters or as XML entity format

Comment: @AlokVishwakarma  What does post your data as parameters mean? Can I parse out the json values and create a request acceptable to the server?

Comment: Diffrence:
if in my server side script i am only accepting header application/json then i will check  for it, if incoming payload is in request content type having application/json then i will process the data, otherwise script will return false.

Comment: please go thru both below image you will get better under standing for both
parameters post request URL Image
http://i67.tinypic.com/wu4v9.png

Json post request image 
http://i65.tinypic.com/2b5gns.png

Answer (score 1):

You can use libraries [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) to parse your file to get the json to be posted and then [Request](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/requests/using-requests-in-python) to post. You can get json from response.

1. Use json to get the body as json from you file, something on below line would work

   `import json
   with open('data.json') as data_file:

   data = json.load(data_file)
   payload = data["body"]
   url = data["headers"]["Origin"] //if url also needs to be extracted from file
   headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}`
2. Use request to post the json

   `r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
   resp = r.json()`

There are multiple similar posts ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733638/post-json-using-python-requests), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835559/parsing-values-from-a-json-file-using-python) & [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9746303/how-do-i-send-a-post-request-as-a-json)) can also be referred,

Comment: Interesting. What if the server doesn't accept `application/json` type content?

Comment: If a server has been configured to not to accept json content then why you are posting json, its very much possible server does not have capability to parse jason object also. From client we can not go beyond server capabilities. Refer https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.16 for http response codes can enable you to decode the response you are getting.