# How to make a POST call to a Java Spring REST server by Python and pass a 'map' object?

Tags: python, spring, rest

Here is the REST server code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public MyObject create(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> myMap){
    String nameStr = (String) myMap.get("nameStr");
    String labelStr = (String) myMap.get("labelStr");
    return new MyObject(nameStr, labelStr);
}
```

How do I call this server by Python?

Comment: Use the requests module in python

Comment: If you control the server code, you can improve it with a proper DTO; what you have now is not very good. It's expecting JSON like `{"nameStr": "...", "labelStr": "..."}`. Also it doesn't seem to really *do* anything...

Comment: I think what you're trying to ask is: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9746303/3001761

Comment: @jonrsharpe, thank you very much!!! This works for me.

Answer (score -1):

Using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/):

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.post('http://yourserver.com/create',
...                   data = {'nameStr': 'Your Name', 'labelStr': 'Your Label'})
```